# Binary search tree better than normal array of elements?

Tags: arrays, search, binary-search-tree

I am not sure about the statement whether it is completely true or not, but if it is true, please answer me why it is so.

According to me, binary search tree has `O(log n)` complexity but in case of skewed input it again becomes `O(n)` which is same as in case of simple storing and searching in an array. So how is it better or it is not?

Edit: The scenario is: We would need to continuously insert and search for data in runtime and this has to be optimised.

Comment: As in so many other things when talking about code, the answer is "it depends". The biggest factor is how the data structure in question is used. Is it built once and then queried repeatedly? is it built and then constantly modified, and only occasionally queried? Is it built and then only walked once to extract the objects? .......

Comment: @KarolyHorvath "better" means faster in terms of time taken in building the set and searching for a number(say).

Comment: @twalberg Query is made to the DS and as well as it would get modified in runtime(like new values are inserted and not deleted).

Answer (score 2):

If you ask about the performance, that depends on the application. However, I can explain in brief what exactly happens and how it works.

```
 ARRAY
```

An array allows random access to each element in it. The complexity for a particular element is O(1) for insert, delete and find. The max/min, delete in O(n). Also, we can make max/min O(1) and delete O(n) instead. If your array is sorted, it will cause insert/delete to be O(n), but you will gain O(logn) find, and O(1) min/max.

```
BINARY SEARCH TREE
```

Binary search tree, on the other hand, is sorted by definition. An unbalanced Binary Search Tree, it has O(n) in the worst case. However, for balanced Binary Search Tree, it gives a complexity of O(logn).
The complexity can be O(1) min/max any how for both.

Arrays are also usually faster to iterate if the order of traversal is not important, since you gain better cache performance. Also, since an array is unbounded size by nature, an array requires reallocation and copying the data when your array is full.

Usually when you are planning to insert data and keep it sorted, Binary Search Tree is preferred. But if you want to randomly access/traverse, usually use an array.

Have a look at this: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1107717

Comment: Can you please be specific regarding the scenario given in the edit.

Comment: "The max/min, delete in O(n)" - depends on whether you care about the order. if not, it's O(1).

Comment: @GautamSingh: you could write a whole chapter in a book comparing those two approaches. the most important thing you have to know: measure it!

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I agree with you and I did mention that the complexity differs depending upon whether we care about the ordered or unordered array/bst.

Comment: @GautamSingh You mention in the edit that you have to "continuously insert and search for data in runtime", however you do not mention whether its sorted or not. To keep it optimised, take a sorted data and use BST. But like i mentioned, the complexity depends on the order.

Comment: @newDevGeek When someone says that data would be coming on runtime without any other constraints, it simultaneously means that the data will be random, if I am not wrong.!